# Dynamically set a variable in variables section of robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

I want to set the current date as a variable in variables section. The problem is that in variables section I cannot call any robot keywords. Is their a way to do this using python?

for example:

my .robot looks like this:

```
Variables***
${current_date}    2021-9-2
```

and I would like to set the date dynamically with something like this:

```
Variables***
${current_date}    date.today()
```

Answer (score 2):

As of robot framework 3.2 you can use [inline python evaluation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#inline-python-evaluation), which lets you put any python code inside `${{` and `}}`

Example:

```
*** Variables ***
${current_date}  ${{ datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you add variable in your testcase it is just a string.
Setting variable dynamically can be done with variable file. This example is taken from the [documentation.](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-and-variable-files)
All you have to do, is crate variable file and then add this file to your testcase.

```
import os
import random
import time

USER = os.getlogin()                # current login name
RANDOM_INT = random.randint(0, 10)  # random integer in range [0,10]
CURRENT_TIME = time.asctime()       # timestamp like 'Thu Apr  6 12:45:21 2006'
if time.localtime()[3] > 12:
    AFTERNOON = True
else:
    AFTERNOON = False
```

Comment: The variables will be evaluated only once, on importing the file, and not changed afterwards. E.g. they are dynamic in their initialization, but not afterwards.

Comment: @TodorMinakov I think the OP wants dynamic initialization though.

Comment: Well it's ambiguous :) Your answer is good, I left the comment mainly as a hint for someone else coming to the question and expecting the variable to be fully dynamic.